# C++ post increment is executing before the body of a for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm going totally crazy here. I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I can't help but think it has a bug in it, or otherwise I've just forgotten some serious fundamentals.

It seems that when I remove the "initialization" (first field) of my for loop, my "post-increment" (third field) executes prior to the body of the loop.

```
std::list<VideoTranscoderStats>::iterator videoStatsIter = mTranscoderStatisticsList.begin();
for(;videoStatsIter != mTranscoderStatisticsList.end();videoStatsIter++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

As I debug, I can see that I'm executing "videoStatsIter++" before "do stuff", and also before testing the condition in the for loop.

On the other hand, if I move my initialization of videoStatsIter into the beginning of the for loop statement, everything works fine. "videoStatsIter++" is executed following the body of the for loop.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user2623967 The question is, is the OP doing something wrong or otherwise misunderstanding correct C++ behaviour, or did they really hit a bug in VS2008.

Comment: Unless you somehow screwed up somewhere in the code we don't see, it indeed looks like a compiler bug. It's certainly no correct C++ behaviour *as far as I can tell from your description and code*. But I have to say I'm quite surprised VS2008 would screw up on something as fundamental...

Comment: Hmmm, post-increment takes a copy that'll be assigned at end of the loop maybe? What's the value seen inside the loop, does it still equal to `mTranscoderStatisticsList.begin()` on the first iteration?

Comment: Are you tracing the debug or release version?  From your description, it looks like you are trying to debug the release version.

Comment: That's why I usually prefer prefix-increment when using iterators in for loops BTW. It's more efficient, regarding copying iterators around.

Comment: @cup Right, I didn't think about that. This is quite likely indeed.

Comment: Can you expand on why you think this is the case? What do you see, precisely?

Comment: So, I don't seem to be executing the body of the loop at all. My list has one element in it, but it's being bypassed.

Comment: @cup: I am using Debug version

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: I can also try executing this in Linux (gcc) and see what happens.

Comment: Do you disable all optimizations?

Comment: @vmayer Are you able to reproduce it with simpler data, in a clean project? eg. `std::list<int>`

Comment: @DieterLucking: I didn't create this project, so not sure off hand. Let me know if there are specific compile options I should look for.

Comment: @syam: I could try that

Comment: I tried repeating the same thing with a list of ints, containing one element. Works fine. Doesn't do the post-increment first.

Comment: @DieterLucking: I don't think there are optimizations. If I go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Optimization for the project, all options seem to be off.

Comment: A wild guess: The MSVC debugging code is doing it.

Comment: Are you really sure it is incrementing before checking the condition?  Try setting a breakpoint at the iterator assignment.  When it hits the breakpoint, press Alt 8 - this will disassemble the code.  In the disassembly, set breakpoints on the condition, the increment and the first statement of the body and continue.  Which one does it hit first?  If it hits the condition first then you don't really have a problem.

Comment: @cup: I'm sure it's incrementing first because I have a single entry in my list, yet the body of the for loop is not being entered. Isn't that convincing? And if I add the "initialization" to the first statement of the for loop, everything works fine: the incrementing function is not entered until the loop has been traversed once.

Comment: Also, I have run the same thing in gcc and it behaves fine.

Comment: Try typedef std::list<videotranscoderstats> videotranscoderstatslist.  Then use the typedef'd declaration throughout rather than the inline definition.